# c# / Xamarin Camera Plugin

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile

I am learning C# and i am trying to develop a mobile application where a user can sell and buy stuff. 
User can add an advert and part of that is that he is able to either capture photos directly or from his own gallery.

I have media plugin which works perfectly, what I am failing is to be able to temporarily store and display pictures on the Adding page. My aim is that once user will capture a picture it displays as MainImage once he presses button Take Picture again the previous picture is supposed to move to MainImage2 location and so on.. the Main image is the biggest display so once he captures the new picture he will have a chance to decide if he wants to advert it or has take a different picture.

In total he should be able to take 5 pictures and display them on his advert.

This is my quick xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CarouselPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Baltazar.Controls"
             xmlns:templates="clr-namespace:Baltazar.Views.Templates"
             xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:Baltazar.Resources"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin"
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Baltazar.Views"
              x:Class="Baltazar.Views.AddingPage">
    <ContentPage BackgroundColor="{ StaticResource BackgroundColor }">

        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout Spacing="-1">
                <Grid Grid.Row="0"  VerticalOptions="Start"  RowSpacing="0">
                    <!--ToolBar-->
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <templates:HeaderItem Grid.Row="0"></templates:HeaderItem>
                    <AbsoluteLayout Grid.Row="0">
                        <!--Notifications-->
                        <Image Source ="{DynamicResource Notificatons}"
                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.95,0.40,30,30" 
                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional,YProportional" 
                           BackgroundColor= "Transparent">
                        </Image>
                    </AbsoluteLayout>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" RowSpacing="5" Padding="20,0,20,10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ProgressBar Grid.Row="0" IsVisible="True" BackgroundColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Frame Padding="20,15,20,5" Grid.Row="1"  HasShadow="True" HeightRequest="140" WidthRequest="100">
                        <Image x:Name="MainImage" Grid.Row="1"/>

                    </Frame>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Padding="0,10,0,0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>

                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Frame HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="43" Grid.Column="0">
                            <Image x:Name="MainImage1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        </Frame>
                        <Frame HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="43" Grid.Column="1">
                            <Image x:Name="retSource"  Grid.Column="1"/>
                        </Frame>
                        <Frame HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="43" Grid.Column="2">
                            <Image x:Name="MainImage3" Grid.Column="2"/>
                        </Frame>
                        <Frame HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="43" Grid.Column="3">
                            <Image x:Name="MainImage4" Grid.Column="3"/>
                        </Frame>
                        <Frame HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="43"  Grid.Column="4">
                            <Image x:Name="MainImage5" Grid.Column="4"/>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="3" Padding="20,20,20,10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height ="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height ="Auto"/>

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style ="{StaticResource SecondaryButton}" Text="{x:Static resources:LabelCZ.ButtonTakePicture}" Clicked="TakePicture_Clicked"/>
                        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style ="{StaticResource SecondaryButton}"  Text="{x:Static resources:LabelCZ.ButtonUploadPhoto}" Clicked="UploadPhoto_Clicked" />
                        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style ="{StaticResource SecondaryButton}" Text="{x:Static resources:LabelCZ.ButtonTakeVideo}" Clicked="TakeVideo_Clicked" />
                        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style ="{StaticResource SecondaryButton}" Text="{x:Static resources:LabelCZ.ButtonUploadVideo}" Clicked="UploadVideo_Clicked" />
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>


        </ContentPage.Content>

    </ContentPage>

</CarouselPage>
```

and here is the code behind..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SQLite;
using Baltazar.Helpers;
using Baltazar.Model;
using Plugin.Media;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Plugin.Media.Abstractions;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Baltazar.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class AddingPage : CarouselPage
    {
        AdLogEntry adLogEntry = new AdLogEntry();
        CameraService cameraService = new CameraService();
        public byte[] imageAsBytes;
        public string pathLabel;

        public AddingPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async  void TakePicture_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Nemame přístup", "Nelze nalezt kameru", "OK");
                return;
            }

            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions

            {
                PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium,
                Directory = "Sample",
                SaveToAlbum = true,
                Name = "test.jpg"
            });

            if (file == null)
                return;

            await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

            pathLabel= file.Path;

            MainImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => // display
            {
                var stream = file.GetStream();
                return stream;
            });

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) // image in bztes
            {
                file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
                file.Dispose();
                imageAsBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

            }


        }
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            ImageSource retSource = null;

            if (value != null)
            {
                byte[] imageAsBytes = (byte[])value;
                retSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));
            }

            return retSource;
        }
        public void MovePicture()
        {
            if (retSource != null)
            {
                MainImage1.Source = retSource;


            }
           else 
        }
```

My question is if you please can point me in the right direction how to do this.

Comment: Do you have a web api setup for storage? what setup do you have right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can have a model:

```
public class User
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name{get; set;}
   public List<Picture> Pictures{get; set;}
}

public class Picture
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Url{get; set;}
    public byte[] Image{get; set;}
}
```

Now you can have a list of pictures with their `byte[]`, with this you can display them temporarily. After taking a picture add the Image to the list of pictures and update your UI ( You can do this automatically with MVVM pattern).

For persistency, you can use sqlite for local storage and azure for cloud storage. There are tons of libraries out there to easily integrate this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thank you, well I want to first store them in files and once i get my head around api i will transfer it all there. I have sqlite set, but from what I understood is that sqlite is not good for pictures..

Comment: You won't store the byte[] but the location of the picture which is why there is a URL property. The byte[] Image property is only for temporary data to display them in real time after taking the picture or choosing one.